# SQL fetch xml data attribute and values from non xml type column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, openfire, sqlxml

How to retrieve xml type data from non xml type column using SQL
I am having one table and a column inside it
xml is a column of type ntext

xml column data example is given below

```
<message to="4075@abc.myftp.org" type="chat" from="5082@abc.myftp.org/e76bea0f">
<body>james bond</body>
<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates" />
</message>
```

I want to fetch "to","from" attribute value and also  tag value

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed the closing tag `</message>` in the xml, but if you add it, you can use `value()` function:

```
declare @temp table (data ntext)

insert into @temp (data)
select '<message to="4075@abc.myftp.org" type="chat" from="5082@abc.myftp.org/e76bea0f">
<body>james bond</body>
<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates" />
</message>'

select
    c.data.value('message[1]/@to', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @temp as t
    outer apply (select cast(data as xml)) as c(data)
```

Comment: Thank you @Roman for the perfect answer and also for quick response

Comment: Hi Roman, i am trying to run this query from PHP application, but getting  error /*****       [nativecode=1934 - SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.]       *****/                                                                              Can you please suggest